# How does my function break `functions`?

Tags: shell, ksh, function

I wrote a ksh function for git checkout (I've removed some irrelevant proprietary components for the sake of the public question, if you're wondering why it's useful to me):

```
# Checkout quicker
checkout(){
if [ "$1" == "master" ]; then
   git checkout master
else
   git checkout $1
fi
}
```

When I look at the function on the command line using `functions`, though, I get an odd output:

```
$ functions checkout
checkout()
}

# Checkout quicker
checkout(){
if [ "$1" == "master" ]; then
   git checkout master
else
  $ <- (this is my PS1, which I'm not writing here because it's big)
```

Why is the function not displaying properly? Did I break `functions` by technically using the function name inside the function? I am using ksh93u+ 2012-08-01 on RHEL.

Comment: What shell are you using? What is `functions`? Is that some shell builtin in your shell? And what operating system?

Comment: @terdon I've added tags with shell and OS. `functions` is an alias for `typeset -f`. I thought it was a built-in, maybe not.

Comment: Can't repro with `ksh --version`: `sh (AT&T Research) 2020.0.0` in Arch Linux

Comment: @muru I'm on 93u+ 2012-08-01

Comment: I tried a Docker container of `centos:7` with `ksh-20120801-144.el7_9.armv7hl` (`ksh --version`: `sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01`). No luck there either. But in my case it doesn't include the comment before the function.

Comment: Is the function definition stored in a file that you source with `.`?

Comment: @stéphaneChazelas I define the `checkout` function inside my .envfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you may have hit the bug later fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/commit/f21ace5cde9b9e91fb93b2b95f9978169f798d9a). I can reproduce it with CentOS 7's ksh93 with:

```
$ cat a
# Checkout quicker
checkout(){
if [ "$1" == "master" ]; then
   git checkout master
else
   git checkout $1
fi
}
$ . ./a
$ functions checkout
checkout(){
if [ "$1" == "master" ]; then
   git checkout master
else
   git checkout $1
fi
}
$ vi a
```

Editing the file the function was sourced from, adding some text before the definition of the function. Now:

```
$ cat a
01234567801234567890123456789
}
# Checkout quicker
checkout(){
if [ "$1" == "master" ]; then
   git checkout master
else
   git checkout $1
fi
}
$ functions checkout
checkout()
}
# Checkout quicker
checkout(){
if [ "$1" == "master" ]; then
   git checkout mast$
```

Quoting that commit's log:

> ### [v1.1] `typeset -f <functname>`: generate script using `sh_deparse()`
>
> Problem reproducer:
>
> - Locate or write a script with a function definition
> - Source the script with `.` or `source`
> - Print the function definition with `typeset -f`; looks good
> - Edit the file to add or remove characters before or in the
>   function definition, or rename or remove the file
> - Print the function definition with `typeset -f` again; the output
>   is corrupted!
>
> Cause: ksh remembers the offset and length of the function
> definition in the source file, and prints function definitions by
> simply dumping that amount of bytes from that offset in the source
> file. This will obviously break if the file is edited or (re)moved,
> so that approach is fundamentally flawed and needs to be replaced.

Comment: Gosh, what a find. Kudos.